# Project Euler Problem 8 - Largest product in a series

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge

I am new to python3 and tried to solve the task in a very basic way. Please critique my code. I appriciate any suggestions for improvement.

Here is the question:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the
>   greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> **Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have
>   the greatest product. What is the value of this product?**

My Code:

```
s = '7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'

listem = []
listem2 = []
highest = 1
pp = 13
sonuc = 1

for i in range(1001 - pp + 1):    
    listem.append(s[i: i+pp])
    for digit in listem[i]:
        listem2.append(digit)
    listem2 = [int(k) for k in listem2]
    for q in listem2:
        sonuc *= q
        if highest < sonuc:
            highest = sonuc
    sonuc = 1
    listem2 = []

print(highest)
```

Comment: I'd probably take `highest` to be 0 or -1; in case the dataset contains too many zeros.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest (but not computationally most efficient) way to solve this challenge is to use a brute-force algorithm, like you did. However you can write it a lot more succinctly when using more of the tools available in the Python standard library.

- Use a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to get all slices:

  ```
  s = "..."
  n = 13
  slices = (s[i:i+n] for i in range(len(s) - n))
  next(slices)
  # '7316717653133'
  ```
- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) this string to an iterable of integers:

  ```
  slices = (s[i:i+n] for i in range(len(s) - n))
  list(map(int, next(slices)))
  # [7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3]
  ```
- Use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) to get the product of this iterable:

  ```
  from functools import reduce
  from operator import mul

  slices = (s[i:i+n] for i in range(len(s) - n))
  reduce(mul, map(int, next(slices)))
  # 5000940
  ```
- Use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) to...get the maximum of those:

  ```
  slices = (s[i:i+n] for i in range(len(s) - n))
  max(reduce(mul, map(int, slice)) for slice in slices)
  ```
- Finally, wrap the code in functions and the calling code in a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do):

  ```
  from functools import reduce
  from operator import mul

  def prod(x):
      return reduce(mul, x)

  def maximum_product(s, n):
      return max(prod(map(int, s[i:i+n])) for i in range(len(s) - n))

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      s = "..."
      n = 13
      print(max_product(s, n))
  ```

Comment: I appriciate all your suggestions,,

Answer (score 2):

Essentially your algorithm

- partitions a string of integers into integer-sublists of a fixed size
- iterates over each sublist of integers
- computes the product for each sublist
- then updates the maximum-possible-product if the most recent product is larger

That's a perfectly logical way to solve the problem.

But there are some algorithmic gains to be had (which I won't code up for you, because you'll gain more from writing it up yourself).

In essence, each time I take the product of 5 integers, I have to do 4 multiplications. So if I wanted to compute the product of the first, and the second, 5 integers in the string `624919...`, that is, the product of (6,2,4,9,1) and (2,4,9,1,9), is there a more efficient way to do it than to compute the products independently?

It turns out there is. First I compute the product (2,4,9,1), then to get the first answer I multiply this by 6, and to get the second I multiply it by 1. Doing the products independently requires 8 multiplications; doing the products with info about the overlaps requires 5 multiplications.

Think about how you could use a "sliding window" approach to more efficiently calculate the 13-mer products. Be careful of the zeros.

From a code-review point of view:

- 1) Separate parsing the input data from processing that data

  - `int_string = '12345....'`
  - `int_list = [int(x) for x in int_string]`
- 2) Wrap your algorithm in a function (list[int], int) -> int; and call it

  - `def largest_p_product(ints, p): ... <copy in your code> ...`
  - `result = largest_p_product(int_list, 13)`
  - `print(result)`
- 3) Consider what might happen with inappropriate data

  - what if the list[int] is shorter than `pp`
  - what if the input string contains non-digit characters?
  - what if the list[int] is all zero?

Comment: I appriciate all your suggestions,,